# Side-scrolling shooter game for the Macintosh from the 1990s

Tags: apple-macintosh, identify-this-game

I'm trying to find an early to mid 90s Macintosh game.

- It was a side scrolling shooter in the style of R Type.
- You flew a spaceship that looked vaguely like the USS Enterprise from Star Trek, albeit with a mass of guns up front.
- You flew over a landscape that contained, among other things, civilian cities.
- You could shoot straight ahead and also drop bombs (I think?).
- The title screen showed a large image of the player ship.
- The overall tone was somewhat whimsical.
- It was likely a shareware title.

It's been bugging me for years that I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is a vague description. But the Enterprise (saucer section?) and massive guns in front do ring a bell:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Side-scroller; fly a spaceship on bombing raids over enemy territory, dodging and/or shooting enemy ships and collecting power-ups; land (carefully) on your own turf; repeat. Graphics and sound quite good, but silly. The most fun, when you can manage it, is cruising along with auto-strafe and invincibility.
>
> Awards: MacWorld Game Hall of Fame, 5 Mice MacUser Magazine.

It's just a guess, but do you think of [Sky Shadow?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Shadow). Like on [Macintosh Repository](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/4842-sky-shadow) or [Macintosh Garden](https://macintoshgarden.org/games/sky-shadow).

Comment: I'm amused that the artist included giant cross-hair sights on the ends of each of the guns, even though they appear to be fixed to the front of the ship, and that sort of thing would only make sense for a handheld weapon anyhow...

Comment: They are obviously needed to distinguish the front from the back and so the guns from the exhaust pipes of the diesel engine which is powering this like-new little jewel, as-new, the previous owner only used it for going to buy the groceries...!